# Why are assumptions in Lean UX written in the form of "we believe ... to be true" and not in the form of "we do not know if ..."?

Tags: user-research, validation, lean-ux

A characteristic of Lean UX is writing down assumptions, which are then used as the basis for design. But should I not rather write down the things I don`t know, and which I want to learn from users?

Comment: In general...  A question is an issue.  An assumption is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

#### Lean process includes both assumptions and research

1. Knowables, not unknowables, lead to design. This should be self evident.
2. The lean UX process is iterative. When confronted with an unknowable you can either do research on it, or make a **testable assumption** and verify it (in Lean UX, assumptions get turned into testable hypotheses).

---

Lean process (from *Lean UX* by Eric Ries)

[image]

---

The combination of research, assumptions and testing turns unknowables into knowables in the Lean UX process.

Comment: Knowables are the decision basis for design. But unkowables also go into the design, as we cannot know everything, when designing. Aren`t these the interesting things, because the unknowables are the uncertainties you have with the design. As designers should we not be humble and admit that there are things we do not know about users?

Comment: There's a difference between knowable assumptions and knowable outcome. "Users would like to make coffee" is a knowable assumption. "Coffee machine makes coffee quickly" is a knowable design outcome. In the lean approach, you can't get to the outcome without first knowing the assumptions (IMO "hypothesis" is a more accurate term). The reason they need to be written down is, clarity around design context drives clarity around design process...this is especially true in team environments.

Comment: We have to test the knowables, but also the unknowables. What bothers me with Lean UX is following aspect: the assumption system „we believe that“ turns unknowables into knowables. You don`t admit, that you lack subject matter knowledge about personas, contexts and workflows. So why don`t we write „we don`t know if“? Is it because we don`t get a "true / false result" from that, when we write it down this way?

Comment: @FormFollowsFunction perfectly valid critique. Lean UX is much less prescriptive than Lean Manufacturing, so I would think it's perfectly fine to note down what you don't know at the beginning of the ideation process. Fortunately as designers we're spoiled for choice with design frameworks so there may be others more suitable to unknowable-rich problem domains (eg user driven design comes to mind for situations where user behavior is not well understood)

Answer (score 1):

Simply because there are probably a multitude of things that you don't know and can make assumptions about, but that would defeat the purpose of being 'lean' in the sense of getting straight down to the point and provide a minimal viable product that you can build and test. It is basically taking a first step and say that of all the possibilities I am choosing to go with this option so I can use it as the basis to build on other assumptions if it is proven to be true, or to change if it is false.

But if you want to take a more 'scientific' way of looking at things, in general when you make a hypothesis, what you want to do is state it in a way so you can try to prove the opposite fact to be true. So for example, if you believe that people like to click on A, you should make the assumption that people like to click on B and try to prove it to be true. That way you can come to the conclusion of A by eliminating B as a possibility rather than trying to find evidence that your own assumption is correct since we tend to be biased in some way and look for things to back our own views.

Answer (score 0):

Basic principle of experiment design: you need something falsifiable. You can't test and falsify a "we don't know if..." statement. You can test and falsify a "we believe..." statement.

That said, I think it's worth including unknowns as well. The key is to have some boundaries so you're not capturing the entire universe (we know almost nothing). I'd encourage tracking unknowns that seem to pose a significant risk to capturing the value you're trying to realize, so you can prioritize things that should be tested or variables that can be controlled.